# Select identity of primary table to which record is inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table let us say `TableA`. I have created a `trigger` which is fired on Insertion, Update or Deletion of record in `TableA` and  inserts record in another table let us say `TableB`. Now where am I finding difficulty is from some of the `stored procedures` of `TableA` I am returning `scope_identity()` of `inserted record`. That must be returned from `TableA's` record while I am getting it from `TableB`. Is there any way to solve this issue? I want `scope_identity()` from `TableA` only, `NOT` from `TableB`. Awaiting for your valuable response.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please post your SP and the trigger code

Comment: It's a rare case, normally last inserted identity of TableA should be returned.

Comment: Like said above can't really help you without seeing the code

Comment: kudos for not saying "updation" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCOPE_IDENTITY() should work in that situation, it should be scoped to your stored proc and the insert to TableA, not the insert done in the trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TestColumn] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TestColumn] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TableA_AIDU]
   ON  [dbo].[TableA]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO TableB ( TestColumn )
    SELECT 'TableA Modified'
END

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertToTableA]
    @ID INT OUTPUT  
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT TableA ( TestColumn )
    SELECT 'Insert from sp_InsertToTableA'
    SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

The stored proc returns the ID from TableA, and the TableB insert is triggered as expected. Are you sure you're not using @@IDENTITY instead of SCOPE_IDENTITY()?

Comment: Thanks.. in most places I was using @@Identity() but replacing them with scope_identity() worked well.. :)

Comment: No problem, I learned a few new things from the docs as well :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx